# 'Configuration' does not contain a definition for 'GetConnectionString'

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing

I'm writing the code for our integration suite and using this example: [integration tests dotnet core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1#sut-environment)

I'm trying to implement the piece that allows for a real db to be used in the tests, but I keep getting the error that Configuration does not contain a definition for GetConnectionString
[image]

Also when I just type Configuration these are the methods that appear: [image]

Do I maybe have the wrong Configuration referenced or something?